# Matching a specific substring in a string with sed

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I have a folder with ebooks in epub format and their names are in the shape "title_of_the_book_-_name_of_the_author". I have to swap the two parts of the names of the ebooks so they become "name_of_the_author-title_of_the_book". I have written this command that works in almost every situations:

```
ls *.epub | sed 's/^\([^-]*\)-_\([^.]*\)/\2-\1/' | sed -E 's/.(.epub)$/\1/g'
```

I'm going to explain the code. First I list all the epub files in the folder, then I match the title of the book and the author of the book and I swap them and finally I delete the  _  that goes at the end of the title of the book. 
This works in almost every situations, but when the title of the book contains a  -  this doesn't work. How can I match the substring  _-  instead of just this character  - ? I think that would solve my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your problem/question correctly, this `sed` expression should do the trick:

```
sed -E 's/^(.*)_-_(.*)\.epub$/\2-\1.epub/'
```

This works under the assumption that every *title* is separated from *author* with a fixed 3-character string `_-_`. We use greedy capturing groups `(.*)`, but anchor the beginning and end of the pattern, so we capture the title and author correctly.

For example:

```
$ echo "title_of_the_book_-_name_of_the_author.epub" | sed -E 's/^(.*)_-_(.*)\.epub/\2-\1.epub$/'
name_of_the_author-title_of_the_book.epub
$ echo "semi-title_of_the_book_-_name_of_the_author.epub" | sed -E 's/^(.*)_-_(.*)\.epub/\2-\1.epub$/'
name_of_the_author-semi-title_of_the_book.epub
```